# How to change colors of all running urxvt instances?

Tags: terminal, colors, urxvt

I'm used to black background and light green text when working on my urxvt terminals. But sometimes, when I take my laptop outside, it becomes hard to read and I'd like to change the colors of all my urxvt instances to black on white, without having to shut them down and reopen again. Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Run them in a multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`...

Comment: @jasonwryan How will this help? Still I'll have to restart all urxvt terminals and then connect each one to the corresponding tmux/screen session.

Comment: Run them all in a single session, detatch, load your alternate `.Xresources` and then reattach. It's not exactly what you want, but it will work...

Comment: John Tyree seems to have worked his way through the very same problem in [his posting on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/565337/urxvt-settings-reload-without-restarting-terminal)